# How can I specify /usr/include/ path in my makefile

Tags: python, makefile

I want to specify the *-I/usr/include/python2.7* path in my makefile. The point being that I don't wish to hard-code this part. I can't really use something like pkg-config since I need this to work on both Mac and Linux. Also can I make it python version independent as well?

Comment: The title of your question doesn't make it clear what you're asking. Perhaps this is why people want to close it?

Comment: @reinierpost That was me voting for closing the question. I wasn't clear about how to frame the question when I did. Now that I have gathered enough background info on the question doesn't make too much sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post here (http://www.trivedigaurav.com/blog/making-makefiles-for-your-research-code/) sufficiently answers the question asked.

It wouldn't be possible to do this with make alone as pointed out by @reinerpost here. Some sort of configure script would be required. One way to do that would be as follows in the post:

Modify the Makefile and call it Makefile.in:

```
LDFLAGS=@PYTHON_LDFLAGS@ @PYTHON_EXTRA_LIBS@
CFLAGS=@PYTHON_CPPFLAGS@ -Wall
```

Now, use autotools to create a configure script which will fill in the variables above. `autoconf` can use the the following configure.ac to achieve this purpose:

> AC_PYTHON_DEVEL([>= '2.5'])

Answer (score 0):

This problem is known to anyone who has ever wanted to write portable Makefiles, and `make` wasn't designed to handle it.

It can be addressed by writing a shell script (usually called `configure`) that figures out where everything is on the system and generates a Makefile based on its findings.  Such a script typically has some heuristics to figure out where everything is. Some such scripts are interactive; some try to figure out everything by themselves.

It's a hell of a job to design the right tests and write such a script, so the next logical step was to create a system that lets you specify the requirements (e.g. "we need python 2.7 or higher") and generates the `configure` script based on that.

A very popular (in the sense of 'often used') toolchain for doing that is [GNU Autotools](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/automake/manual/html_node/GNU-Build-System.html) (see also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system)).

A well-known alternative is [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) (see also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmake)).